# I want to return xml response in Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

In Laravel, I sent a response to front end and the body is xml form
But it arrives in a text form
[Text formatted response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Lys.png)

I set the content-type of response header 'text/xml'
And then echo SimpleXMLElement::asXML()
I want the response body to arrive as a xml form
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bap3M.png)

Comment: Please show your controller code.

Comment: Yes we need to see how you are setting the content type and passing the result exactly.

Comment: Something very suspicious in your first screenshot is that the content starts on line 2, not line 1. I agree with other commenters, though, we can't help you with code we can't see.